# How to add keyframe for data value with script?

Tags: scripting, keyframes

I have the following script:

```
import bpy

for ob in bpy.data.objects:
if "_hitbox" in ob.name:
    ob.follow_bone = False
if ob.pose is not None:
    if ob.pose.bones is not None:
        for bone in ob.pose.bones:
            if ".IKC" in bone.name:
                bone.constraints["IK"].influence = 0
```

At the moment, this script simply sets the values for the entirety of the animation.

How do I make the script keyframe these values? For example at frame 1, follow bone is True, and then I execute the script at frame 20, creating a keyframe where follow bone is False.

Comment: As similiar question have appeared before, do you comprehend the code of the script and/or have you written it yourself?

Comment: @Leander Where would I find those questions? I wrote the script myself: I am an experienced Java and C# programmer, however am new to Python. It is very helpful that, whenever I click something, blender basically prints the code I need to use in the console.

Comment: I was going to answer this Q, but you have already figured it yourself, thanks for contributing =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completed script:

```
import bpy

curr = bpy.context.scene.frame_current;

for ob in bpy.data.objects:
if "_hitbox" in ob.name:
    ob.follow_bone = False
    ob.keyframe_insert("follow_bone",frame=curr)
if ob.pose is not None:
    if ob.pose.bones is not None:
        for bone in ob.pose.bones:
            if ".IKC" in bone.name:
                bone.constraints["IK"].influence = 0
                bone.constraints["IK"].keyframe_insert("influence",frame=curr)
```

To add a keyframe, simply set the value like usual - for example,

```
bone.constraints["IK"].influence = 0
```

And then add a keyframe for that value on the current frame (see top of full script for "curr" variable).

```
bone.constraints["IK"].keyframe_insert("influence",frame=curr)
```

It is possible to set a keyframe on any frame. For example, if I wanted a keyframe at frame 27:

```
bone.constraints["IK"].keyframe_insert("influence",frame=27)
```